# Fluent API equivalent for Data Annotation

Tags: sql, .net, data-annotations, ef-fluent-api

I am not able to use DataAnnotations for setting key and foreign key as I am working on .NET framework. I need to confirm the fluentAPI equivalent of the same.

Below is what i tried, but says "The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE constraint"

model:

```
public class Item
{
   
    public string ItemNo{ get; set; }
    public string parentItemNo{ get; set; }

  // Adding below two navigation properties to existing model
   public virtual Item Parent { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Item> Children { get; set; } = new List<Item>();
 
}
```

DBContext:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
            .HasKey(e => e.ItemNo )
              .HasName("Item$0");
        
         // Adding below lines to create foreign key using fluent API
         entity.HasOne(e => e.Parent)
            .WithMany(e => e.Children)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.ParentItemNo );
```

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework or Entity Framework Core?

Comment: Hi, using entity framework core.

Comment: Can you please try running this in your database: 
`select ParentItemNo from Item WHERE ParentItemNo NOT IN (SELECT ItemNo from Parent)` to check if there are values that don't have any matches. Does it return any results?

Comment: Oh, so this is not between two tables, but a self-referencing relationship, right? In that case please try `select ParentItemNo from Item WHERE ParentItemNo NOT IN (SELECT ItemNo from Item)` - what I'm suspecting is, your existing data is breaking this PK-FK relationship, so you cannot really enforce it. Does Item table has data?

Comment: Will show invalid object name 'parent' if i run that query. I am trying to add 'Parent' and 'Children' navigation properties to existing database model and added the last three lines of DBContext to set foreign key. When i run 'Update-Database' after migration, I get "FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE constraint" error.

Comment: The above said query returns parentItemNo column with data

Comment: Can you please provide the error when updating the database?

Comment: See this article it is doing the same as what you are trying to do:
https://medium.com/@dmitry.pavlov/tree-structure-in-ef-core-how-to-configure-a-self-referencing-table-and-use-it-53effad60bf

Comment: Try to build the relationship under the modelBuilder method like in the link

Comment: @Sarahrb can you please try again after deleting the rows with `ParentItemNo` matching with the result of that query? If you are not working on test data, remember to take a backup.

Comment: @Mithgroth I can see that this error is thrown when some of parentItemNos are empty string. If I make parentItemNo as null, I am able to create new navigation properties. But existing table takes parentItemNo as empty string if not provided. May I know how do I go about this.

Comment: @Samy Sammour Thank you the link was helpful

Comment: @Sarahrb can you please try with `public string? parentItemNo { get; set; }`, forcing this property to be nullable. As far as I can understand from your requirements, an Item may not have a parent. But I'd also advise to use an actual NULL instead of empty string.

Comment: I tried using ?. I still get the same error - The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE constraint "FK_Items_Items_ParentItemNo". The conflict occurred in database "ItemDB", table "dbo.Items", column ItemNo.

Comment: Have you tried turning empty strings into NULLs?

Comment: No I haven't. I can turn the test data to NULL manually now, but may i know if there a way to turn all empty strings to null programmatically

Comment: You can run an update. `UPDATE Item SET ParentItemNo = NULL WHERE ParentItemNo = ''`

Comment: That was perfect. Thank you.

Comment: @Sarahrb posted this as an answer, can you mark it so for future viewers can see the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you are trying to create a PK-FK relationship in the same table, getting the exception:

> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE constraint

indicates a problem in your existing data.

In your case, in `Item` table, there were `ParentItemNo`s with empty string, which is not equivalent to `NULL`, so the database was trying to match these against other records that would have empty string as their `ItemNo`, and this doesn't exist.

Replacing these empty strings to `NULL`s with the following command fixes the problem:

```sql
UPDATE Item 
SET ParentItemNo = NULL 
WHERE ParentItemNo = ''
```